# how to develop option selected based different content div using single page Jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, select, show-hide

We developing the hybrid application.We have an requirement like user select the option and what ever selected the option we want to show the different content.

For an example, user have select option like India,US,Canada.
if user select the India we want display India content remaining hide.
if user select the US we want display US content remaining hide.
If user select Canada we want display Canada content remaining hide.

But we want to display the defualt india the after user select option based we want disply to user.

Any one please tell me how to do for above requirement.It is possible or not?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select1").change(function(){
     
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                $(".box").not(".red").hide();
                $(".red").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
                $(".box").not(".green").hide();
                $(".green").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
                $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
                $(".blue").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="yellow"){
                $(".box").not(".yellow").hide();
                $(".yellow").show();
            }
            else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

```html
<div data-role="content" >
  <select name="select" id="select1">
   <option value="red">QATAR</option>
   <option value="green">United Arab Emirates</option>
   <option value="blue">KUWAIT</option>
   <option value="yellow">OMAN</option>
  </select>

  <div class="red box" id="pageContentQtr">
    <p>content-qatar</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="green box" id="pageContentUae">
    <p>content-uae</p>
  </div>

  <div class="blue box" id="pageContentKwt">
   <p>content-kuwait</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="yellow box" id="pageContentOman">
   <p>content-oman</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is possible.  You need to write onChange event on select and pass relevant value to javascript to hide / show div as per Id

Comment: Adit i modified question. please see it not working, with out selecting any thing or selecting all div's are showing.

Comment: Just add a line above the select to hide all div  $(".red,.green,.blue,.yellow").hide();

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adit_999/wamrb5gd/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adit_999/wamrb5gd/1/  Check Now . Forgoted to include jquery.js

Comment: thaks Adit it's working

Answer (score 0):

```
Add the CSS First
Secound add js

.content{
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.content-qatar{ background: #CCC; }
.content-uae{ background: #CCC; }
.content-kuwait{ background: #CCC; }

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
     $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="content-qatar"){
            $(".content").not(".content-qatar").hide();
            $(".content-qatar").show();
        }
        else if($(this).attr("value")=="content-uae"){
            $(".content").not(".content-uae").hide();
            $(".content-uae").show();
        }
        else if($(this).attr("value")=="content-kuwait"){
            $(".content").not(".content-kuwait").hide();
            $(".content-kuwait").show();
        }
        else{
            $(".content").hide();
         }
     });
  }).change();
 });
 </script>

 <div>
    <select>
        <option>Choose Country</option>
        <option value="content-qatar">Qater</option>
        <option value="content-uae">UAE</option>
        <option value="content-kuwait">Kuwait</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="content-qatar content">content-qatar</div>
<div class="content-uae content">content-uae</div>
<div class="content-kuwait content">content-kuwait</div>
```